# How can I disable error logging to console in react-query v5 in my unit tests?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, tanstackreact-query

Setting a custom logger was deprecated in v4 and is removed in v5, and I cannot disable console logging like before: (https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/custom-logger)
Now I see those errors in my test log.
When I am testing error cases, it now looks like something went wrong in the logs, but everything is fine/intended.

I am using jest and react-testing-library.

Any ideas?

Comment: I started using https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fail-on-console in combination with `jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation()`